# Can't figure out how to have percentage chnnances for something to happen

Tags: python

I am making a text-based game; I am trying to figure out a way to have multiple endings and certain percentages for each to happen, but when I run this, it comes up with weird letters and sometimes multiple endings.

```
choice1_wakeup = input ("Wake Up? Y or N:")
if choice1_wakeup == 'y' or choice1_wakeup == 'Y':
    print ("Placeholder")
else:
    import random
    for x in range(100):
        ending_percent = (random.randint(1,10)) 
        if ending_percent > 2:
            choice1_ending_common = ("You are woken a while later and see the priest holding a knife to your throat for a moment before he slits it and you bleed out.")
            print (random.choice(choice1_ending_common))
        elif ending_percent < 2 and ending_percent >0.5:
            choice1_ending_rare = ("You wake up a little while later and find yourself dangling over the mouth of the sacrificial volcano while your tribe chants the name of the fire goddess, kahuahuahua, kahuahuahua, kahuahuahua. “What’s happening?” you ask the priest. “You are being sacrificed for your crimes” he replies and at that he tosses you into the fiery abyss.","A few minutes later you are woken by  the suddenly extremely cold temperatures. You look around and spot the god of death daharasus. “Why haven’t you completed your rituals to me yet?” he asks you in a stone cold voice. “I’m sorry, I fell asleep” you frightendly reply. “I don’t want excuses!” he screams, he levels his finger at you and you are instantly killed, your soul is forever trapped in the same spot reliving that moment over and over forever.")
            print (random.choice(choice1_ending_rare))
        else:
            choice1_ending_impossible = input ('You are woken up by a stranger a few hours later. "Who are you?" you ask the strange man standing over you. "My name is Jeff Probst" he replies. "I was wondering if you would like to be on my new TV show?" Y or N:')
            if choice1_ending_impossible >= 'y' or choice1_ending_impossible >= 'Y':
                print ("impossible test")
```

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: I'm having an issue with this because the ending that involves jeff probst has to have an input option not just text.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for the `choice` method.  That method picks a random element from the iterable sequence you give it.  In this case, the sequence you provide is the text of a single ending.  The available choices are the individual letters of that ending, so ... you get a single, random character.

If you want to choose a random text, you need to give it a list of strings, such as

```
ending_list = [
    ["You and your team vote Jeff Probst off the island.",
     "You eat five ugly things and win the immunity challenge.",
     "The show is canceled for lack of geologically stable shooting locations."]
```

*Now* you can pick one element from `ending_list`.  Is that enough to get you going?

Comment: Thanks for the help i will try and use this